# when i use wp automatic plugin post shows broken images

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails

when i use wordpress automatic plugin content from some specific feeds are fetched properly but featured images not upload properly and shows like broken image. But when i copy link of that broken image and paste in new tab and hit enter then image shows correctly.

[image]

these images not shows in media option and these uploaded images are not shown in the media.

Comment: You need to take it up with the plugin author. It would be caused by however they handle the images. This isn't a WordPress issue.

Comment: in post images are shows but in media these images not shows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a plugin similar to WP RSS Aggregator, the issue is within the image parameters of the plugin itself. There should be an image parameter setting within the aggregator, assuming you are using the plugin's premium plan.

The way we get around aggregator image issues, is there should be a setting to use a standard feature image for each feed, which only shows about at 1% visitor engagement loss.

All aggregators are fairly archaic, so the solution may not present itself easily.